# MySQL How to get user's activities from users that have had interaction with you?

Tags: mysql, sql, left-join, join

I have a user table, which contains the user's complete name. The linked tables are:

**user**

- **id_user** unique user ID
- **name** user complete name

**user_picture**

- **id_picture**
- **date_added**
- **id_user** id of the user
- **url** url of picture

**user_visit**

- **id_visit**
- **date_visit**
- **id_user_from** this is *you*
- **id_user_to** this is the visited user

**user_question**

- **id_question**
- **date_question**
- **id_user_from** this is *you*
- **id_user_to** this is the visited user
- **question** *this is not relevant*
- **answer** *this is not relevant*
- **flg_answered**

The activity report must display the activity of:

- users' uploaded pictures
- users' answered questions (sent by any user)

...but only from users that I have previously visited, or users that have previously received questions from me.

This is my current query:

```
    SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS
        user.name,
        user_question.date_question,
        user_question.question,
        user_question.answer,
        user_picture.date_picture,
        user_picture.description
    FROM
        user
        LEFT JOIN user_question ON user_question.id_user_to = user.id_user
        LEFT JOIN user_picture ON user_picture.id_user = user.id_user
    WHERE (
            user.id_user IN (
                SELECT id_user FROM user
                INNER JOIN user_visit ON user_visit.id_user_to = user.id_user
                INNER JOIN user_question ON user_question.id_user_to = user.id_user
                WHERE
                    user_visit.id_user_from = 1
                    OR
                    user_question.id_user_from = 1

            )
    )
```

In this example, ID 1 is my user ID. Current issues:

- The order of the results should be chronologically presented (date_visit and date_question)
- The picture and question records are being blended into the same rows. They should be mutually exclusive.

Any ideas on how to fix those 2 issues? Thanks!

Comment: what do you mean the order must be a mix ?  you mean an avg?

Comment: @DavidChan hi! no, i meant that the records should be chronologically presented, despite being of separated tables (pictures and questions).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it looks like you're trying to do two queries, and then intersperse their results by date order...  you probably need to UNION. 
then use a subselect in order to ORDER the results.

```
SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS, *
FROM (

SELECT 
        user.name,
        'picture' as type,
        user_visit.date_visit as date,
        user_picture.date_picture as data1,
        user_picture.description as data2
    FROM
        user
        JOIN user_visit ON (user_visit.id_user_to = user.id_user)
        JOIN user_picture ON (user_picture.id_user_to = user.id_user)
    WHERE user_visit.id_user_from = 1

UNION           

SELECT 
        user.name,  
        'question' as type,
        user_question.date_question as date,
        user_question.question as data1,
        user_question.answer as data2,
    FROM    
        user
        JOIN user_question ON user_question.id_user_to = user.id_user
    WHERE user_question.id_user_from = 1
)

ORDER BY date;
```

Answer (score 0):

To solve the first problem, I think you need to join the user_visit table as well, and ORDER BY the date that way.

```
    SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS
        user.name,
        user_question.date_question,
        user_question.question,
        user_question.answer,
        user_picture.date_picture,
        user_picture.description,
        user_visit.date_visit
    FROM
        user
        LEFT JOIN user_question ON user_question.id_user_to = user.id_user
            LEFT JOIN user_picture ON user_picture.id_user = user.id_user
            LEFT JOIN user_visit ON user_visit.id_user_from = user.id_user
    WHERE (
            user.id_user IN (
                SELECT id_user FROM user
                INNER JOIN user_visit ON user_visit.id_user_to = user.id_user
                INNER JOIN user_question ON user_question.id_user_to = user.id_user
                WHERE
                    user_visit.id_user_from = 1
                    OR
                    user_question.id_user_from = 1

            )
    )
    ORDER BY user_visit.date_visit, user_question.date_question
```

Is that a possibility? Can you please elaborate on your second problem as well? Maybe provide an example?

Comment: actually your last ORDER BY would not comply 1st issue requirement, because it would order the visit dates first, and then the questions date. They should be mixed and ordered.

Comment: Oh, I misunderstood. David's solution is correct, UNIONs are the way to go if you want all results grouped in one column.